# Stored Procedure for select from any table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, create-table

Can create one Stored Procedure for any table just call by name ?

if yes then:

just like this code

```
create PROCEDURE SP_Insert
@TableName as nvarchar(30)
as
begin 
    select * from @TableName
end
```

but I have massage must decalre table variable `@TableName`?

I cant solve this problem

Comment: The code you've posted is T-SQL for MS SQL Server, it is not compatible with MySQL Server.

Comment: Also... _why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: *Can create one Stored Procedure for any table just call by name ?* Yes. Use dynamic SQL ([PREPARE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)) within the SP.

Comment: @Dai want to do that for built one Stored Procedure for all of table not Stored Procedure for each table

Comment: @Akina thanks I will try to use (PREPARE statement)